# How to draw a proper polylines on google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have successfully drawn a polyline from point a to point b, but for some reason , it shows linear line not the correct waypoints

Here's the code

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
        path.addLatitude(3.1970044, longitude:101.7389365)
        path.addLatitude(3.2058354, longitude:101.729536)
        let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
        polyline.geodesic = true
        polyline.map = mapView
```

I was expecting that it would be doing some waypoints, but it just shows straight polylines

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add route between 2 points as polyline?

Comment: yeah as in waypoints.

Comment: If you want the polyline to follow the roads, you need to get it from the DirectionService.

Answer (score 6):

self.googleMapsView is the google maps view.

Example  : self.getDirections("26.9211992,75.8185761", destination: "26.8472496,75.7691909", waypoints: ["26.8686811,75.7568383"], travelMode: nil, completionHandler: nil)

Example: google direction link
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=26.9211992,75.8185761&destination=26.8472496,75.7691909&waypoints=optimize:true|26.8686811,75.7568383

```
   let baseURLGeocode = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
let baseURLDirections = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"

var selectedRoute: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

var overviewPolyline: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>!

var originCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

var destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!


func getDirections(origin: String!, destination: String!, waypoints: Array<String>!, travelMode: AnyObject!, completionHandler: ((status: String, success: Bool) -> Void)?) {
    if let originLocation = origin {
        if let destinationLocation = destination {
            var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originLocation + "&destination=" + destinationLocation
            if let routeWaypoints = waypoints {
                directionsURLString += "&waypoints=optimize:true"

                for waypoint in routeWaypoints {
                    directionsURLString += "|" + waypoint
                }
            }
            print(directionsURLString)
            directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let directionsData = NSData(contentsOfURL: directionsURL!)
                do{
                    let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(directionsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                    let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

                    if status == "OK" {
                        self.selectedRoute = (dictionary["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>)[0]
                        self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                        let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                        let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                        let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                        let originAddress = legs[0]["start_address"] as! String
                        let destinationAddress = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_address"] as! String

                        let originMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.originCoordinate)
                        originMarker.map = self.googleMapsView
                        originMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.greenColor())
                        originMarker.title = originAddress

                        let destinationMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.destinationCoordinate)
                        destinationMarker.map = self.googleMapsView
                        destinationMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.redColor())
                        destinationMarker.title = destinationAddress

                        if waypoints != nil && waypoints.count > 0 {
                            for waypoint in waypoints {
                                let lat: Double = (waypoint.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[0] as NSString).doubleValue
                                let lng: Double = (waypoint.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[1] as NSString).doubleValue

                                let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng))
                                marker.map = self.googleMapsView
                                marker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImageWithColor(UIColor.purpleColor())

                            }
                        }

                        let route = self.overviewPolyline["points"] as! String

                        let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)!
                        let routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
                        routePolyline.map = self.googleMapsView
                    }
                    else {
                        print("status")
                        //completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("catch")

                   // completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            print("Destination is nil.")
            //completionHandler(status: "Destination is nil.", success: false)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Origin is nil")
        //completionHandler(status: "Origin is nil", success: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: this helped me.Thank u

Comment: Thanks Very helpful (Y)

Comment: @sfg2k please update the code for swift 4.2

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3.0 
Please use this code...

```
func getDirections(origin: String!, destination: String!, waypoints:    Array<String>!, travelMode: AnyObject!, completionHandler: ((_ status:   String, _ success: Bool) -> Void)?) {

        if let originLocation = origin {
            if let destinationLocation = destination {
                var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originLocation + "&destination=" + destinationLocation
                if let routeWaypoints = waypoints {
                    directionsURLString += "&waypoints=optimize:true"

                    for waypoint in routeWaypoints {
                        directionsURLString += "|" + waypoint
                    }
                }
                print(directionsURLString)
                directionsURLString = directionsURLString.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)
                DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: { () -> Void in
                    let directionsData = NSData(contentsOf: directionsURL! as URL)
                    do{
                        let dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: directionsData! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                        let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

                        if status == "OK" {
                            self.selectedRoute = (dictionary["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>)[0]
                            self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                            let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

                            let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                            self.originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                            let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                            self.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                            let originAddress = legs[0]["start_address"] as! String
                            let destinationAddress = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_address"] as! String

                            let originMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.originCoordinate)
                            originMarker.map = self.mapView
                            originMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "mapIcon")
                            originMarker.title = originAddress

                            let destinationMarker = GMSMarker(position: self.destinationCoordinate)
                            destinationMarker.map = self.mapView
                            destinationMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "mapIcon")
                            destinationMarker.title = destinationAddress

                            if waypoints != nil && waypoints.count > 0 {
                                for waypoint in waypoints {
                                    let lat: Double = (waypoint.components(separatedBy: ",")[0] as NSString).doubleValue
                                    let lng: Double = (waypoint.components(separatedBy: ",")[1] as NSString).doubleValue

                                    let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng))
                                    marker.map = self.mapView
                                    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "mapIcon")

                                }
                            }

                            let route = self.overviewPolyline["points"] as! String

                            let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)!
                            let routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
                            routePolyline.map = self.mapView
                            routePolyline.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 44, green: 134, blue: 200)
                            routePolyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
                        }
                        else {
                            print("status")
                            //completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("catch")

                        // completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                print("Destination is nil.")
                //completionHandler(status: "Destination is nil.", success: false)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Origin is nil")
            //completionHandler(status: "Origin is nil", success: false)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func drawMap ()
{

    let str = String(format:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(originLatitude),\(originlongitude)&destination=\(destinationlatitude),\(destinationlongitude)&key=AIzaSyC8HZTqt2wsl14eI_cKxxxxxxxxxxxx")


    Alamofire.request(str).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

        let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
        print(resJson)

        if(resJson["status"].rawString()! == "ZERO_RESULTS")
        {

        }
        else if(resJson["status"].rawString()! == "NOT_FOUND")
        {

        }
        else{

            let routes : NSArray = resJson["routes"].rawValue as! NSArray
            print(routes)

            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.sellerlatitude, longitude: self.sellerlongitude)

            let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
            marker.icon = UIImage(named: "mapCurrent")
            marker.title = "Customer have selected same location as yours"
            marker.map = self.Gmap

            let position2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.Buyyerlatitude, longitude: self.Buyyerlongitude)

            let marker1 = GMSMarker(position: position2)
            marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "makeupmarker")
            marker1.title = self.locationAddress
            marker1.map = self.Gmap

            let pathv : NSArray = routes.value(forKey: "overview_polyline") as! NSArray
            print(pathv)
            let paths : NSArray = pathv.value(forKey: "points") as! NSArray
            print(paths)
            let newPath = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: paths[0] as! String)


            let polyLine = GMSPolyline(path: newPath)
            polyLine.strokeWidth = 3
            polyLine.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            polyLine.map = self.Gmap

            let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: position, coordinate: position2)
            let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(170, 30, 30, 30))
            self.Gmap!.moveCamera(update)

        }
    }
}
```

**For swift 5**

```
    func drawMap(SourceCordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D, destinationcordinate :CLLocationCoordinate2D)
   {
       self.mapView.clear()
       let str = String(format:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(SourceCordinate.latitude),\(SourceCordinate.longitude)&destination=\(destinationcordinate.latitude),\(destinationcordinate.longitude)&key=\(googleServiceKey)")
       print(str)
       Alamofire.request(str).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
           let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
           print(resJson)
           let routes : NSArray = resJson["routes"].rawValue as! NSArray
           if(resJson["status"].rawString()! == "ZERO_RESULTS"){}
           else if(resJson["status"].rawString()! == "NOT_FOUND"){}
           else if routes.count == 0{}
           else{
               let routes : NSArray = resJson["routes"].rawValue as! NSArray
               let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: SourceCordinate.latitude, longitude: SourceCordinate.longitude)
               /*let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
               marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_usermaplocation")//UIImage(named: "ic_MapPinGreyIcon")
               marker.title = "" // Addres
               marker.map = self.mapView
               let position2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destinationcordinate.latitude, longitude: destinationcordinate.longitude)
               let marker1 = GMSMarker(position: position2)
               marker1.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_usermaplocation")//UIImage(named: "ic_LocationPinRedIcon")
               marker1.title = "" // Destination Address
               marker1.map = self.mapView*/
               let pathv : NSArray = routes.value(forKey: "overview_polyline") as! NSArray
               let paths : NSArray = pathv.value(forKey: "points") as! NSArray
               let newPath = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: paths[0] as! String)
               let polyLine = GMSPolyline(path: newPath)
               polyLine.strokeWidth = 5
               polyLine.strokeColor =  .black
               let ThemeOrange = GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor( .black)
               let OrangeToBlue = GMSStrokeStyle.gradient(from:  .black, to:  .black)
               polyLine.spans = [GMSStyleSpan(style: ThemeOrange),
                                 GMSStyleSpan(style: ThemeOrange),
                                 GMSStyleSpan(style: OrangeToBlue)]
               polyLine.map = self.mapView
               let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.sourceLat, longitude: self.sourceLong, zoom: 15.0)
               self.mapView.animate(to: camera)
               /*let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: position, coordinate: position2)
                let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 400, right: 100))
                self.objMapVIew!.moveCamera(update)*/
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Finally got something that really works..! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NavalHasan welcome brother

Comment: @AzharhussainShaikh Please update the code for swift 5

Comment: @DavenderVermaSoni please check the updated code for swift 5

Comment: @AzharhussainShaikh , I need the code include the waypoints . Its only for drawing the path from source to destination

Comment: @DavenderVermaSoni if you might noticed the response of the above google directions api you wil get the array of "routes" i think you can find the waypoints from that array.

Comment: @AzharhussainShaikh  Sir but I have my own waypoints . I am saving lat long after every 10 m distance change by user , Saving in database, So I want to create a path from start to end using those waypoints.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919676/swift-google-maps-draw-waypoint-polyline

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement to [Azharhussain Shaikh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6897825/azharhussain-shaikh) answer.

```
func drawMap (src: CLLocationCoordinate2D, dst: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        let str = String(format:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(src.latitude),\(src.longitude)&destination=\(dst.latitude),\(dst.longitude)&key=AIzaSyBKV************")

        Alamofire.request(str).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in

            let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
            print(resJson)

            if(resJson["status"].rawString()! == "ZERO_RESULTS")
            {

            }
            else if(resJson["status"].rawString()! == "NOT_FOUND")
            {

            }
            else{

                let routes : NSArray = resJson["routes"].rawValue as! NSArray
                print(routes)

                let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: src.latitude, longitude: src.longitude)

                let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                marker.icon = UIImage(named: "mapCurrent")
                marker.title = "Customer have selected same location as yours"
                marker.map = self.mapView

                let position2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dst.latitude, longitude: dst.longitude)

                let marker1 = GMSMarker(position: position2)
                marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "makeupmarker")
                marker1.title = "aa"
                marker1.map = self.mapView

                let pathv : NSArray = routes.value(forKey: "overview_polyline") as! NSArray
                print(pathv)
                let paths : NSArray = pathv.value(forKey: "points") as! NSArray
                print(paths)
                let newPath = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: paths[0] as! String)


                let polyLine = GMSPolyline(path: newPath)
                polyLine.strokeWidth = 3
                polyLine.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
                polyLine.map = self.mapView

                let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: position, coordinate: position2)
                let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsetsMake(170, 30, 30, 30))
                self.mapView!.moveCamera(update)

            }
        }
    }
```

To call the function :

```
let fromLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude1, longitude1)
let toLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude2, longitude2)

drawMap(src: fromLoc, dst: toLoc)
```

What I have changed:
1. Parameter passing
2. Position was given statically. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the points for the route. To get the route you need to use Google Direction API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/. Then use the 1st result of array that will be the shortest one, use the encoded path to draw a poly line using pathFromEncodedPath: method.

Comment: Can you show me some codes.