# SWIFT: google maps draw waypoint polyline

Tags: swift, google-maps

Hi I wonder if there is a method to draw a waypoint between two or more markers in google maps iOS. I don't want to draw straight lines... but use just public roads. Here is some of my code to draw straight lines but its not what i am looking for.

```
    @objc private func makeGpsPath(){
    for i in 0 ..< trailArr.count {
        path.add(trailArr[i])
    }
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.black
    polyline.map = mapViewContainer
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To draw polylines between points two ore more you should use google map request read this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints
in my case i did

```
    func drawRoute() {
    ServerCommunicator.getDotsToDrawRoute(positions: positions, completion: { path in
        self.route.countRouteDistance(p: path)
        self.polyline.path = path
        self.polyline.strokeColor = UserSession.tintColor
        self.polyline.strokeWidth = 4.0
        self.polyline.map = self._mapView
    })
}
```

and the part with request

```
static func getDotsToDrawRoute(positions : [CLLocationCoordinate2D], completion: @escaping(_ path : GMSPath) -> Void) {
    if positions.count > 1 {
        let origin = positions.first
        let destination = positions.last
        var wayPoints = ""
        for point in positions {
            wayPoints = wayPoints.characters.count == 0 ? "\(point.latitude),\(point.longitude)" : "\(wayPoints)|\(point.latitude),\(point.longitude)"
        }
        let request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json"
        let parameters : [String : String] = ["origin" : "\(origin!.latitude),\(origin!.longitude)", "destination" : "\(destination!.latitude),\(destination!.longitude)", "wayPoints" : wayPoints, "key" : googleAPI_KEY]
        Alamofire.request(request, method:.get, parameters : parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
            guard let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                else {
                    return
            }
            if let routes = dictionary["routes"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                if routes.count > 0 {
                    var first = routes.first
                    if let legs = first!["legs"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                        let fullPath : GMSMutablePath = GMSMutablePath()
                        for leg in legs {
                            if let steps = leg["steps"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                                for step in steps {
                                    if let polyline = step["polyline"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                        if let points = polyline["points"] as? String {
                                            fullPath.appendPath(GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: points))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                completion(path: fullPath)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
extension GMSMutablePath {

func appendPath(path : GMSPath?) {
    if let path = path {
        for i in 0..<path.count() {
            self.add(path.coordinate(at: i))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: am getting this error
Value of type 'GMSMutablePath' has no member 'appendPath'

Comment: I edited answer, forgot to add extension which i used

Comment: what is 
self.add ? in that extension.
i tried with your updated code. now i can see markers but path is missing

Comment: does your path exists? to draw it you must use polyline with path you got from api

Answer (score 5):

To draw polyline between two markers on GoogleMap in Swift 3.

```
// Pass your source and destination coordinates in this method.
func getPolylineRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    
    let url = URL(string: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)&destination=\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)&sensor=false&mode=driving")!
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription) // Handle error here
            return
        }
        
        do {
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] else {
                return
            }
            guard let routes = json["routes"] as? [Any] else { return }
            guard !routes.isEmpty else { return }
            guard let overview_polyline = routes[0] as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let polyString = overview_polyline["points"] as? String else { return }
            
            //Call this below method to draw path on map
            self.showPath(polyStr: polyString!)
            
        }catch{
            print("error in JSONSerialization \(error)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

To draw polyline on map .

```
func showPath(polyStr :String){
    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
    polyline.map = mapView // Your map view
}
```

Comment: @VinothVino did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
private func drowRoute(){

let path = GMSMutablePath()
    path.addLatitude(self.lat!, longitude: self.long!)
    path.addLatitude(self.destLat!, longitude: self.destLong!)
let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeWidth = 2.0
polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
polyline.geodesic = true
polyline.map = mappView

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   let point3 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(30.7173), longitude: Double(76.8329))

  let point4 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(30.6942), longitude: Double(76.8606))
    let point5 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(30.7465), longitude: Double(76.7872))
   var arrOfWayPoints : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                                    arrOfWayPoints.insert(point3, at: 0)

                                    arrOfWayPoints.insert(point4, at: 1)

                                    arrOfWayPoints.insert(point5, at: 2)



                                    self.drawRouteWithWaypoint(positions: arrOfWayPoints as! [CLLocationCoordinate2D])

 static var distance = Double()


    func drawRouteWithWaypoint(positions:[CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
        LiveJob.getDotsToDrawRoute(positions: positions, completion: { path in
            //self.route.countRouteDistance(p: path)
            self.polyline.path = path
            self.polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            self.polyline.strokeWidth = 2.0
            self.polyline.map = self.mapView
        })

        self.lblDistance.text = String(LiveJob.distance)
    }

    static func getDotsToDrawRoute(positions : [CLLocationCoordinate2D], completion: @escaping(_ path : GMSPath) -> Void) {
        if positions.count > 1 {
            let origin = positions.first
            let destination = positions.last
            var wayPoints = ""
            for point in positions {
                wayPoints = wayPoints.characters.count == 0 ? "\(point.latitude),\(point.longitude)" : "\(wayPoints)|\(point.latitude),\(point.longitude)"

            }
            let request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json"
            let parameters : [String : String] = ["origin" : "\(origin!.latitude),\(origin!.longitude)", "destination" : "\(destination!.latitude),\(destination!.longitude)", "wayPoints" : wayPoints,"mode" : "Transit","key" : "AIzaSyCtMHyxPEModWK8IgzBD96hQMFL-UCIjcY"]
            Alamofire.request(request, method:.get, parameters : parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                guard let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                    else {
                        return
                }
                if let routes = dictionary["routes"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    if routes.count > 0 {
                        var first = routes.first
                        if let legs = first!["legs"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {

                            let newLeg = legs[0]
                            let distance = newLeg["distance"]
                           // LiveJob.distance =  LiveJob.distance + distance!.doubleValue



                            let fullPath : GMSMutablePath = GMSMutablePath()
                            for leg in legs {
                                if let steps = leg["steps"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                                    for step in steps {
                                        if let polyline = step["polyline"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                            if let points = polyline["points"] as? String {
                                                fullPath.appendPath(path: GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: points))
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    completion(fullPath)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```