# iOS connecting multiple points for bus route with google map sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps

I can't simply use **GMSPolyline** to connect those multiple point because it will pass over building.

As in this link, I also can't use Google Direction API because by doing that, I think I need to query like at least 100 times because I need to draw line for more than 100 points.

[How to draw a proper polylines on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763080/how-to-draw-a-proper-polylines-on-google-maps)

My data is something like this. It will have more than 100 points.

```
    {
        "bus_stop_id" = 59331;
        lat = "1.42297587494";
        long = "103.832825717";
    },
            {
        "bus_stop_id" = 59061;
        lat = "1.42563677968";
        long = "103.834966133";
    },
            {
        "bus_stop_id" = 59671;
        lat = "1.42777383";
        long = "103.835186";
    },
```

How shall I do?